# "You will be informed of this by email" - or is it "informed of that"?

Tags: pronouns

From a [lang-8 post](http://lang-8.com/1289414/journals/177781919893737485373366654481152344213):

> Once the necessary documents have been received, your account will be activated and you will be informed of **that** by email.

I've recommented to change the pronoun **that** to **this**. But why exactly? **This** signals greater proximity relative to **that**, and sometimes emotional proximity, according to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/76189/48335).

Is the 'emotional distancing' conveyed by **that** the main obstacle? Or is it also technically wrong to use **that** in "you will be informed of __ by email"? Are there instances where we can use **that** in this phrase and be sure that it sounds natural?

Comment: I prefer "that" over "this" in that sentence. "Once the necessary documents have been received, you will be informed of that (action) by email". I think maybe it's because of the timing of the events. The activation is at some indeterminate time after receiving the documents as opposed to "this is what I'm going to do". If I were writing it, I might say "Once the necessary documents have been received, you will be informed by email when your account has been activated."

Comment: I would be likely to say "that" but would be likely to write "this".

Comment: If forced to choose between the two, I would personally pick *this* but either is fine.  Honestly, I would have written "informed of *it* by email."  I think it's largely personal preference in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Captain, where are we going on this mission?
-- You will be told of that when the time comes.

Dear Mrs Smith,
I regret to inform you that your husband, John, won't be coming home. He was sent on a dangerous mission to one of the moons of Jupiter, and his rocket ship has malfunctioned and cannot take off again. There will be no rescue mission. He was informed of this before he left but decided to go on the mission anyway.
Sincerely,
Buck Rogers

Comment: In your Buck Rogers example, "He was informed of this (fact) before he left" seems to be a little different from "After we've made the calculations, we will launch the rescue mission and you will be informed of that by telegraph."

Comment: Emotional as well as temporal proximity<>distance are  factors, I think.